# Can we integrate WhatsApp From Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

I want to Integrate WhatsApp From Marketing Cloud . Can we do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, I fear there are no out-of-the-box functionalities to accomplish this task.

Perhaps your team can take advantage of the Journey Builder custom activities. Yet this requires a solid background in development.

Build Custom Activities and Events
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm

As you can see below there have been ideas from other customers related to Whatsapp.

Integration With WhatsApp
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZZ7QAO

SALESFORCE CRM INTEGRATION WITH WHATSAPP
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TtbxQAC

Digital Engagement WhatsApp Business Messaging FAQs
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000352588

Comment: is there any other way ?

Comment: Not in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible within the standard features of Marketing Cloud. There might be 3rd party solutions allowing you to do so, but I don't have adequate knowledge of these to recommend one over the other.

You should also observe the [limits](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/rate-limits/) WhatsApp has on the number of messages you can send during a 24 hour period.

Answer (score 1):

GroupConnect only supports LINE and Facebook Messenger at this time, however, [Direct Messenger](https://www.direct-messenger.com/) is a third-party Custom Activity that enables you to send WhatsApp messages to Contacts in a Journey.

[image: Direct Messenger]

Comment: i want to send that link it in email

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific in your question then...